# Highcharts stacked bar

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular9

How Can I use Stacked bar HighCharts in Angular 9.any example?
I have tried using the code from Highcharts official site but cant use the same in angular code .all the references found online are not appropriate or wont work.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way will be to use the officially supported Highcharts wrapper for Angular - [highcharts-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-angular)

```
<highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="chartOptions"></highcharts-chart>
```

---

**Live example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-aeyhm5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular